# Which API key to use for IBM Speech-to-Text with IAMAuthenticator? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

How do I set this up correctly? The description seems straight-forward

```
import os
import json

from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

api_key='XYZ'
service_endpoint='https://api.eu-gb.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com'

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(api_key)
speech2text = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)

speech_to_text.set_service_url(service_endpoint)

speech_models = speech_to_text.list_models().get_result()
print(json.dumps(speech_models, indent=2))
```

Which API key do I have to pass to the 'IAMAuthenticator'?

I don't quite understand if I first have to create an Instance/Resource (https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/speech-to-text) and use that API key, or only create and use an IBM Cloud API key (https://cloud.ibm.com/iam/apikeys). I have tried different combinations of the above, but cannot connect successfully, raising `ApiException: Error: Provided API key could not be found, Code: 400`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you use `IAMAuthenticator` with the API key. Don't forget to import it.

See the example in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#authentication) and more information about the SDK in the [README](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk#iam). Can you make a call with curl with the same API key and URL

(The `BasicAuthenticator` is specifically for username and password auth.)

Answer (score 0):

To use the APIKEY directly you must use the `BasicAuthenticator` instead of the `IAMAuthenticator` from `ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators`. See the code snippet below:

```
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1, ApiException
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import BasicAuthenticator


...


# Basic Authentication with Watson STT API
stt_authenticator = BasicAuthenticator(
    'apikey',
    '<insert_your_watson_stt_apikey_here>'
)

# Construct a Watson STT client with the authentication object
stt = SpeechToTextV1(
    authenticator=stt_authenticator
)

# Set the URL endpoint for your Watson STT client
stt.set_service_url(
    '<insert_your_watson_stt_endpoint_url_here>'
)

# Read audio file and call Watson STT API:
with open(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), './.',
        'audio_sample.flac'
    ), 'rb'
) as audio_file:
    # Transcribe the audio.flac with Watson STT
    # Recognize method API reference: 
    # https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize
    stt_result = stt.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        content_type='audio/flac',
        model='pt-BR_BroadbandModel'
    ).get_result()

# Print STT API call results
print(json.dumps(stt_result, indent=2))

...
```

I hope this answer helps you.